# While developing a Rails 7 app, what changes in the code base require me to restart the server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-7

I have e file in lib.  It appears that if I change that file, I need to stop and restart the server to pick up the changes.  In the past, most of the items in the config directory required me to stop and restart the server before they took affect but I've been surprised a few times that things took effect without a restart.

What files do not get automatically reloaded?

Answer (score 0):

By default anything outside of the `app` directory.  See `Rails.application.send :_all_autoload_paths` and [config.autoload_paths](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#config-autoload-paths) for how to add more.